# Creating Word Addin for 2007 and 2010

Tags: vsto, word-2007, word-2010

I'm very new with VSTO development. Is it possible to develop Ms Word Add-In that can be used in Word 2007 and Word 2010?

When I try debugging an add in for Word 2010 in a machine that have Word 2007, it is said that "the required version of the Microsoft Office Application is not installed". Same thing happen when I try debug add in for Word 2007 with a machine that have word 2010.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is certainly possible to create a vsto addin that runs on both office 2007 and 2010 but there are some restrictions on the what and how. Microsoft has created a rather comprehensive document about this topic: [Running Solutions in Different Versions of Microsoft Office](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb772080.aspx)